# Weird field notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, finite-fields

I have a question:

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be any field characteristic $0$. Recall that $x_i$, denotes the $i^{th}$ entry of a vector $x\in\mathbb{F}^n$. Define
>
> $$S = \{x\in\mathbb{F}^5 \mid x_i = x_{6-i}, 1 \leq i \leq 5 \}$$
>
> $$T = \{x\in\mathbb{F}^5 \mid x_1 = x_4 = 0\}$$
>
> Prove that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^5$

So like is this meaning like $5$-tuples? $(a,b,c,d,e)$? What is this $\mathbb{F}^5$ stuff?

A field characteristic = 0 just means a determinant is not invertible right?

Comment: Characteristic zero excludes the appropriateness of finite fields, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some help:

$$\mathbb{F}^5=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)| x_i\in\mathbb{F}\}.$$

So, you need to show that $S=\{(a,b,c,b,a)|a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}\}$ is a subspace. Can you do that?

Comment: Well $a=b=c=0$ means it holds a zero vector.

$(a,b,c,b,a)+(x,y,z,y,x) = (a+x,b+y,c+z,b+y,a+x)=(t,u,v,u,t)$

$\alpha(a,b,c,b,a) = (\alpha a, \alpha b, \alpha c, \alpha b, \alpha a) = (f,g,h,g,f)$

Is all it takes, being zero vector, closure under addition and multiplication right? Hence $S$ is a subspace?

Comment: @user142198 Yup!! Well done!

Comment: Is $(a,b,c,b,a)$ the basis of $S$?

Comment: @user142198 What do you think? How many degrees of freedom do you have? What do you think the dimension has to do with the degrees of freedom?

Comment: Three degrees I believe, and I would hazard a guess that $dim(S)=3$ aswell then.

Three vectors $Span(S) = a(1,0,0,0,1) + b(0,1,0,1,0) + c(0,0,1,0,0)$

Comment: @user142198 Indeed they are!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb F^5$ is the $\mathbb F$-vector space of all $5$-tuples over $\mathbb F$.

Characteristic $0$ means that in $\mathbb F$,
$$1 + 1 \neq 0,\quad 1 + 1 + 1\neq 0,\quad 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\neq 0,\ldots$$

Comment: So in a finite field, the characteristic $n$ is the number of elements in the field, so in a field $F = {0,1,2,3,4}$ we have $1+1+1+1+1=0$ Characterstic of $F$ is $5$

Comment: @user142198 No, in a finite field the characteristic is no necessarily the number of elements. For example, let $F=\{(x,y)\,|\,x,y\in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\}$ with addition given by $(x,y)+(x',y')=(x+x',y+y')$ and multiplication  given by $(x,y)\cdot(x',y')=(x\cdot x'+\overline{2}y\cdot y',x\cdot y'+x'\cdot y)$, then $F$ is a finite field of characteristic five with more than five elements.